# Can someone help on how to enter a long position at a lower band of Bollinger Band in Pine script

Tags: compiler-errors, pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have this code below but it enters when the bar close, I do not want.. I need to enter at a current price below the lower band -

```
// Long Entry Condition
long_condition = ta.crossunder(close, lowerBand) 

// Short Entry Condition
short_condition = ta.crossover(close, upperBand)
```

is it posible to enter a long position when prices touches the lower band, or at the actual/current price below the lower band!?

I tried something like this but it does not work -
`def touch(band, price)`:

```
Check if the price touches the band.

Parameters:
- band: The value of the band (e.g., upper or lower Bollinger Band).
- price: The current price.

Returns:
- True if the price touches the band, False otherwise.

return price <= band + 0.0001 and price >= band - 0.0001
```

Comment: Is this a `strategy()` or an `indicator()`?